# Replace a loop (and a conditional inside it) with direct access by index

Tags: c++

I have a for loop with a condition inside it to find a value of a buffer at an `index`:

```cpp
// uint index = ...
// const float *bufferPtr = ...
// uint stride = ...
// uint vertexCount = ...

for (uint i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++) {
    float xVal = *bufferPtr++;
    float yVal = *bufferPtr++;
    float zVal = *bufferPtr++;
    bufferPtr += stride;
    if (i == index) {
        qDebug() << "Vertex coord: " << xVal << " , " << yVal << " , " << zVal;
    }
}
```

I try to replace the for loop (and condition inside it) with such direct access by index:

```cpp
float xVal = *(bufferPtr + index * stride + 0);
float yVal = *(bufferPtr + index * stride + 1);
float zVal = *(bufferPtr + index * stride + 2);
qDebug() << "Vertex coord without loop: " << xVal << " , " << yVal << " , " << zVal;
```

But output logs give me **different** results:

```
Vertex coord:  14.574  ,  -8.236  ,  7.644
Vertex coord without loop:  20.67  ,  -19.098  ,  18.536
Vertex coord:  14.552  ,  -8.024  ,  7.842
Vertex coord without loop:  -0.361096  ,  0.109164  ,  0.926117
Vertex coord:  14.722  ,  -8.18  ,  7.842
Vertex coord without loop:  20.648  ,  -19.052  ,  18.522
```

I cannot figure out why the results are different :(

---

### FIX

As suggested by @LanceDeGate answer, the issue was resolved by reducing `stride` by `3` before the loop:

```cpp
stride = stride - 3; // Three floats per vertex

for (uint i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++) {
    float xVal = *bufferPtr++;
    float yVal = *bufferPtr++;
    float zVal = *bufferPtr++;
    bufferPtr += stride;
    if (i == index) {
        qDebug() << "Vertex coord: " << xVal << " , " << yVal << " , " << zVal;
    }
}
```

Now the logs are the same:

```cpp
Vertex coord:  -0.522632  ,  -0.803892  ,  -9.02102
Vertex coord without loop:  -0.522632  ,  -0.803892  ,  -9.02102
Vertex coord:  -0.39095  ,  -2.04955  ,  -8.91668
Vertex coord without loop:  -0.39095  ,  -2.04955  ,  -8.91668
Vertex coord:  -0.259928  ,  -0.804899  ,  -9.03231
Vertex coord without loop:  -0.259928  ,  -0.804899  ,  -9.03231
```

Comment: You know the [] operator? You know that pointer arithmetic takes size of object, which the pointer points to? You know `struct`? I have no idea why your code is so complicated. Can you give some background info why you need to do all the access by handcrafted pointer arithmetic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's because a whole *stride* is added to the bufferPtr, after three "bufferPtr++"s.

Maybe this is what you mean:

```
float xVal = *bufferPtr;
float yVal = *(bufferPtr+1);
float zVal = *(bufferPtr+2);
bufferPtr += stride;
```

or

```
float xVal = *bufferPtr++;
float yVal = *bufferPtr++;
float zVal = *bufferPtr++;
bufferPtr += (stride-3);
```

Comment: The issue was the `stride`, I updated the question with the results!

Answer (score 1):

A first hint:

Please provide if possible a full example which everybody can compile. It takes some time to get your code up and running...

OK, as I understand your! code is something like that:

```
float var[]= { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
size_t elements = sizeof(var)/sizeof(float);
int stride = 2;
int vertexCount = elements/(3+stride);

void f( float* bufferPtr, int index )
{
    for (uint i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++)
    {
        float xVal = *bufferPtr++;
        float yVal = *bufferPtr++;
        float zVal = *bufferPtr++;
        bufferPtr += stride;
        if (i == index) {
        std::cout << "Vertex coord: " << xVal << " , " << yVal << " , " << zVal << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

can be simplified to:

```
void f2( float* bufferPtr, int index )
{   
    struct Data
    {
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;
        float dummy[2]; // stride
    };

   Data& d = (reinterpret_cast<Data*>(bufferPtr))[index];
   std::cout << "Vertex coord: " << d.x << " " << d.y << " " << d.z << std::endl;
}   


int main()
{   
    f( var, 2 );
    f2( var, 2 );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Upvoted! I'm going to implement `f2` as a lambda function and check the results =)

Answer (score 1):

With the following test case, I get the correct result:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  float tabla[16] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
  unsigned int index = 0;
  const float *bufferPtr = &tabla[0];
  unsigned int stride = 2;
  unsigned int vertexCount = 2;

  for (uint i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++) {
    float xVal = *bufferPtr++;
    float yVal = *bufferPtr++;
    float zVal = *bufferPtr++;
    bufferPtr += stride;
    if (i == index) {
      std::cout << "Vertex coord: " << xVal << " , " << yVal << " , " << zVal << std::endl;
    }
  }
  const float *bufferPtr2 = &tabla[0];
  float xVal2 = *(bufferPtr2 + index * stride + 0);
  float yVal2 = *(bufferPtr2 + index * stride + 1);
  float zVal2 = *(bufferPtr2 + index * stride + 2);
  std::cout << "Vertex coord without loop: " << xVal2 << " , " << yVal2 << " , " << zVal2 << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Vertex coord: 0 , 1 , 2
Vertex coord without loop: 0 , 1 , 2
```

I didn't change your code at all, essentially. The only difference is that I added both tests in one main function, and obviously use a different buffer pointer (`bufferPtr2`) that I initialise with the first address of the table `tabla`. Are you sure you reset your pointer before trying the alternative method? It's hard to say because you've only provided snippets of your code.

Comment: Thanks! I upvoted your helpful answer =) I don't run both approaches along side each other. I replace the loop completely then compile and run again. I'm not sure what the cause is!